# tf.keras.layers.Conv2D.trainable_variables is empty

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer

I am trying to use keras layers in my tensorflow model. But the layers do not create any trainable variables. For example, the code below returns empty list.

```
import tensorflow as tf


class ResidualBlock(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv2d = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size, padding='same', input_shape=(64, 64, 16))

    def __call__(self, x):
        return x + self.conv2d(x)


rb = ResidualBlock(3)
print(rb.conv2d.trainable_variables)
```

Should not the trainable variables of a conv2d layer include the kernels and biases for the layer? Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you call it, it will "build" it and initialize the weights:

```
rb(np.random.rand(1, 64, 64, 16))

for variable in rb.conv2d.trainable_variables:
    print(variable.name)
```

```
conv2d/kernel:0
conv2d/bias:0
```

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.